# Which scripture contains the story of Lord Venkateswara?

Tags: scripture, venkateshwara, reference-request

Which authentic Hindu scripture contains the total story of Lord [Venkateswara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venkateswara)?

From where one can read it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Skanda Purana has a lot about Venkateswara.

From [this chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana23.html) of the book "Essence of Skanda Purana" (hosted @ Kamakoti.org):

> Sage Suta prescribed an eight-fold Bhakti Route to Lord Venkateswara:
>   1)To display and ensure ‘Sneha Bhava’(feeling of friendship) towards
>   His Bhaktas (devotees); 2) To perform service to ‘Bhagavat Bhaktas’and
>   satisfy them; 3) To perform Puja to Bhagawan with sincerity; 4) All
>   the actions of the Self are to be targetted to Bhagavan;
>    ..... Those who are fortunate to have even a glimpse of the fantastic
>   Idol of Venkateswara do experience the awe and satisfaction that
>   leaves behind a lasting familiarity and nearness.Those who think of
>   Srinivasa, either out of curiosity, or greediness, love of
>   materialism, or fear or casual occurrence undergo a definite
>   transformation of outlook, approach to life and morality. If such
>   casual approach has a multiplier effect, could one imagine the far
>   reaching impact of the Eight-folded dedication!

And, from [this chapter](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana22.html) of the same book:

> Varaha Deva described to Bhu Devi that Emperor Akash decided to
>   perform a Grand Yagna on the banks of Arani and while tilling, he
>   found a girl child and as he was issueless, brought her up as their
>   own, named as Padmavati. Once Sage Narad met Padmavati as she was
>   grown up as an eligible bride and predicted that she would be the wife
>   of Lord Srinisasa of Venkatachal. Almost immediately she met a
>   Stranger in the Royal Garden and introduced himself as Anant or
>   Veerapati from Venkatachal Mountain and that he was hunting a wolf.
>   Padmavati’s companions rebuffed Ananta Deva that hunting was
>   prohibited in their garden. Anantha returned but desired intensely
>   that Padmavati should become His life partner and sent Vakulamala to
>   the court of Emperor Aakash to negotiate their wedding. The Emperor
>   had no bounds of joy and the holy wedding of Lord Venkateswara and
>   Padmavati took place in style and grandeur when Devi Lakshmi was
>   present to make Padmavati happy and comfortable,

Comment: Does it contain the whole story of Lord Venkateswara?

Comment: @hanugm I am not sure but probably it does not have.